# Storing symbols as a user input

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to make a Sports Betting Calculator in java where I need the user to input a + or - sign.  I want to read that sign and be able to go into my if statements.  I was wondering how to recognize that symbol since string doesn't recognize it.  This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MoneyLineCalc {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Sports Bet Calculator");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Is it a (+ or -)?: ");
    String x = scan.nextLine();

    String +;

    if (x == +){

       }


    }
}
```

I do understand that instead of a "+" or "-" i could use a letter, but for this program i want to use those symbols.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the string variable does not matter, rather the input String value. Hence, try this :

```
String plus = "+";

if (x.equals(plus)){

   }
```

Similarly for `String minus="-"`

Answer (score 0):

`String`, in this case, refers to the type of your variable `x`. This means that `x`'s value is a sequence of characters. Remember, variable names cannot start with numbers or even contain operators.

You don't want to compare the name of the variable with the user input. You really want to compare the variable's **value** to (in this case) `"+"` or `"-"`. Using the `=` operator enables you to assign a value to a variable.

So to compare what the user inputted to either the **value** `"+"` or `"-"`, you could use the `equals()` method. Ex:

```
if(x.equals("+"))
{
    //Do work
}
else if(x.equals("-"))
{
    //Do other work
}
```